# How to configure all subprojects that are using NodePlugin in Gradle

Tags: node.js, gradle, build, build.gradle, gradle-node-plugin

I have a multi-project, and a few of its subprojects use [the Gradle Plugin for Node](https://github.com/node-gradle/gradle-node-plugin).

*./subproject/build.gradle*:

```
// GitHub: https://github.com/node-gradle/gradle-node-plugin
plugins {
    id "com.github.node-gradle.node" version "3.4.0"
}
// ...
```

I would now like to configure all of these subprojects from the root `build.gradle`.

*./build.gradle*

```
pluginManager.withPlugin('what.do.i.put.here') {
    node {
        download = true
    }
    // ...
}
```

Now my **question**: What do I have to put in as parameter for `withPlugin`? Where do I find the "official" plugin name to use?

Comment: Would you mind to show me  full `build.gradle`

Comment: I am having trouble to set the [Gradle Plugin for Node.](https://github.com/node-gradle/gradle-node-plugin) with yarn NextJS project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `pluginManager` I found the following way to achieve this:

```
// This is executed on all subprojects
subprojects {
    // This is executed on all subprojects that use the NodeJS plugin (https://github.com/node-gradle/gradle-node-plugin - npm_<...> (e.g., npm_install))
    plugins.withId('com.github.node-gradle.node') {
        node {
            download = true
        }
```

It uses `plugins.withId` inside of `subprojects`, using the ID also specified in the `plugins` section: *com.github.node-gradle.node*